# Setting values to TexImage3D function in SharpGL C#

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

C++ Code using OpenGL:

```
vector<RGB> LUT;  //creating a vector3 array
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGB, 16, 16, 16, 0, GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT, &LUT[0]);
```

The above C++ code is working fine. `&LUT[0]` is accepted as it is of type `const GLvoid * data`

C# Code using SharpGL:

```
Vector3[] vec3 = new Vector3[2]; //creating a vector3 array
gl.TexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGB, 16, 16, 16, 0, GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT, &LUT[0]);
```

My problem is, in SharpGL `&LUT[0]` is not accepting, stating the message that it accepts only IntPtr types. Is there anyway I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pack `float[]` into an `IntPtr`.

```
float[] data = {
    ...
};
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr dataPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(float)) * data.Length;
```

Remember to free it after having called `gl.TexImage3D()`.

```
handle.Free();
```

Comment: @conamx did you get around to testing it? Did it work?

Comment: First of all, thank you. Yes, following your instructions, I was able to initialize **gl.TexImage3D()** function. Program was compiled successfully. However, I'm getting the error **FatalExecutionEngineError**  when I run the program. I'm sure this is something to do with SharpGL library so this time I'm trying openTK library